# Deployment of self hosted integration runtime in azure synapse using azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm working on building the CICD pipeline for deployment of Azure Synapse Analytics workspace using Azure DevOps. I was reading [this](https://craigporteous.com/ci-cd-for-azure-data-factory-how-to-handle-self-hosted-integration-runtimes/) article and see a need to handle the deployment of self hosted integration runtime and the underlying linked services a bit differently but I am not sure how to set it up. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the best approach is to create the self hosted integration runtime on all environments manually, with the same name, and then your CI\CD deploys should work without a problem.

Comment: Hi @ChenHirsh I have the self hosted integration runtime created in all the different environments with the same name and after deployment to any of the environments it defaults to the `AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime`. Unable to figure out what's causing this.

Comment: Its not supported at this time.